# Project Disappears from Project Explorer -Eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse

I have been using Kepler for about a week now. The version used is

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. 
>    Version: Kepler Service
>   Release 1 Build id: 20130919-0819

Today when I opened Eclipse IDE, all my projects disappeared (except 1 out of 10 projects).
I restarted Eclipse as well as laptop for couple of time but it didn't help.

When Eclipse starts, all my projects are visible for two seconds in the project explorer. After 2 seconds it disappears and only one project is visible.
I tried importing wizard to import all my projects. After selecting root directory, the projects are visible but are all disabled (i.e. I am not able to select from the list.).

All of these projects were created on Kepler and was visible till yesterday. I didn't do any preference customization and the IDE was not updated as well.

Please help me debug this issue.

Comment: It might be on a drive which needs administration rights like your windows partition, try launching eclipse with administration rights, right click on eclipse and select run as administrator

Comment: There is no permission issue here. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and eclipse is in my home path.

Comment: Found it.. Filtering on Project Explorer View was on for some strange reason. Removed the filtering and now all projects are listed.

Comment: Well then i would recommend that you answer your own question and mark it solved :)

Comment: I'm sorry. Totally forgot to do this. I will do it immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering on Project Explorer View was turned on. Removed the filtering and now all projects are listed.